# With three many-to-many relationships in Rails, how can I find one, given the other two?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :seasons_teams, :dependent => :destroy                          
  has_many :seasons, :through => :seasons_teams
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
  ...
end

class Season < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :players_seasons, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :players, :through => :players_seasons
  has_many :seasons_teams, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :teams, :through => :seasons_teams
  ...
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :players_seasons, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :seasons, :through => :players_seasons
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
  ...
end
```

There will be validations such that any given player can have at most one team for each season.

I am looking for an efficient way to get a players team for any given season, i.e.:

```
@player.team(@season)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this ought to work:

```
@player.teams.joins( :seasons ).where( :season_id => @season.id ).first
```

To get the nice concise syntax you're looking for you would use it in a scope, e.g.:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_season, lambda do |season|
    joins( :seasons ).where( :season_id => season.id )
  end
  # ...
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def team season
    teams.for_season( season ).first
  end
end

@player.team @season
# => #<Team:0x...>
```

Comment: That gives `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "season"`, but the following works: `joins(:seasons).where('season_id = ?', season.id)`

Answer (score 0):

```
@player.teams.find_by_season_id(@season.id)
```

Comment: undefined method `find_by_season_id' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you either have a typo or a mistake in your team class. I think you should have:

```
has_many :seasons, :through => :seasons_teams
```